# JavaScript - How does AJAX data request appear in the url?

Tags: javascript, ajax

when sending `AJAX` request from client side to server side (if I'm not wrong) we often send data like this :

```
var postData={name: John, psd: 123 , description : "student"};
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/user", false); 
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json-application");
xhttp.send(postData);
```

I'm not sure how does the sent data `postData` appear in the url to the server. I'll be glad if someone can help me or guide me to some materials or articles.

Comment: It doesn't appear in the URL the way a query string dose in a GET request. That property makes it useful for more sensitive data: I log all incoming URLs (and recommend others do too) but not POST data so my server logs (shouldn't) contain any sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your confusion is related to a misconception about `POST` requests. `POST` requests can post **data** to servers. This data (thankfully) **does not have to** be in the `url` as **query string**. Indeed, that's how web gets secured by HTTPS. So data could be sent to a server in a POST request in two separate ways: **query string** and **post data**. I hope that helps.

Comment: hi thank you for illustrating , but I have question ,if that ,then how can I get this data? (post request)

Comment: @user8244016 you can see it in request payload in the browser. Or you could use data binding server side (I'm from C# background). Check this link:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-can-i-see-the-post-body-in-chrome-developer-tools-example-app

Comment: @user8244016 you're have to specify which server side language and/or framework you're using...

Comment: @jcaron server in node.js

Comment: `request.body` but you'll need some middleware to parse the relevant post data format. Check out https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/README.md#bodyparserjsonoptions

Answer (score 1):

It will be sent as a `POST` request, which is sent through a HTTP header rather than through the URL.

If you were using a `GET` request, it would appear in the URL like so:

```
http://localhost:8080/user?name=John&psd=123&description=student
```

Answer (score 1):

When making a post request the data sent to the server will appear in the body/payload of the http request after the headers which is separated by a line break.

Only get requests appear in the url.

If you want to read more about post requests check out Mozilla 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

For http protocol: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview